# jQuery - set calculated div width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to set on my page posts as cards to one div with id="content" (like on G+).

```
#content {
    margin-top: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    height: auto;
}
.card {
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;

}
```

and I want to calculate how much `.card` I can fit into the screen.
So I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict"; 
    var cardAmount = (Math.floor($(window).width/520))*520;
    $("#content").css("width", cardAmount);

});
```

but the problem is(I think) the second parameter of `.css` must by string and it's not.

Comment: You forgot the brackets after `.width`. Change it to `.width()`: [**working result**](http://jsfiddle.net/nquhwh7z/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you need to add a unit to this number so the CSS engine knows what to do with it.

Also, there's another problem with your code - your not calling width **function** here: `$(window).width`. Please remember that width is a function from jQuery API, not DOM API parameter that you can simply get like this. So the whole fix is quite simple:

```
var cardAmount = Math.floor($(window).width() / 520);
$("#content").css("width", cardAmount + "px");
```

Here - see how it works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxeqyghc/)

Comment: It's working perfectly! Thank you! This script for calculating width was wrong too(it calculated just how much cards can screen display, not how much have to by width of #content, but I updated it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the syntax with the px or % in the css .

```
$("#content").css("width", cardAmount+"%");#or
$("#content").css("width", cardAmount+"px");#or
$("#content").css("width", cardAmount+"em");
```